# I am using angular translate to label or string conversion, i don't know how to translate the placeholder text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<section layout="row" layout-align = "center center" layout-padding>
<div flex = "50" flex-xs = "100">
    <jb-input layout="column" jb-input-type="text" jb-  
    model="gSearchCtrl.gSearchQuery" jb-
    change="gSearchCtrl.onInputModelChange" jb-placeholder="Search profiles,  
    doubles teams, games, matches, tournaments..." jb-autofocus="true"></jb-
    input>
</div>
```

-So how to convert that placeholder

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, inside your Input:

```
<jb-input layout="column" jb-input-type="text" jb-  
    model="gSearchCtrl.gSearchQuery" jb-
    change="gSearchCtrl.onInputModelChange" jb-placeholder="{{ 'SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}" jb-autofocus="true"></jb-
    input>
```

Then you will have the Index 'SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' defined in your translate References.